How to convert String to date range
I want to convert the strings in the following format to java.util.Date range, start and end date:
January 16th – 21st, 2025
January 16th – February 21st, 2025
January 16th – February 21st, 2025
December 16th 2024 – January 2nd 2025
November 16th – 19th

you have examples of different months and different years and also examples without years that should use the current year
Do you have any idea how I should process all these formats?

java.util.Date represents timestamps not dates. Yes, you might think: That's preposterous, why would they name a thing that explicitly does not represent a Date as Date? But, it's a fact. Check the apidocs. There's a reason every date related aspect of it (such as .getYear(), certainly something a Date object would have) is deprecated with a note that this is because it doesn't work properly. What you want, is java.time.LocalDate.

You should be using java.time.Period if the range part is important or two LocalDates otherwise

@g00se a Period, as far as I know, merely represents the notion of e.g. "4 months and 8 days", not "from jan 16th to jan 21st, 2025".

Difficult to know without knowing what the use case is in detail. Period::between takes two LocalDate. A parser of some sort will have to be built for those input strings

First of all, you need to know all the possible date range formats.  For example, the last one is November 16th – 19th and does not seem to have any year (and you'll need a year to form any kind of date in Java).

i have shared all the possible cases, Period is not useful for this use case but I don't mind using LocalDate as long as I can get a starting date and ending date

the format without a year is fine, i can add the year before parsing

or you can use MonthDay if year is not needed ... but mixing both (with and without year) can be a mess

what you mean by MonthDay? how is that going to solve the problem ?

"the format without a year is fine, i can add the year before parsing" --> "or you can use MonthDay ..."

MonthDay will be good but not sufficient. You will probably need regexes as well

The ideal solution is to use standard ISO 8601 formats rather than localized text for exchanging date-time values textually: 2025-02-16/2025-02-21. See LocalDateRange class in ThreeTen-Extra library.

i don't have control over the data i receive so not possible to change the format, however it is a readable format so why not parsable

I want to convert the strings in the following format to java.util.Date range ... No, you definitely do not want to do that. java.util.Date had bad design problems and has been outdated the last 10 years, fortunately. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Others have already mentioned the correct types to use, LocalDate and probably MonthDay.

Are you sure you want comma between day and year in February 21st, 2025 and not in December 16th 2024 – January 2nd 2025??

Am I observing correct that the dates are always in the future? So August 25 - 28 without year would imply 2025? Would today‘s date be allowed as start date?

May start and end be the same date? If so, is that notated November 5th - 5th, 2024 or just November 5th?

It appears your format is basically this:
month day[[,] year] – [month] day[[,] year]

I would probably go with a regular expression:
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Year;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class DateRangeParser {
    
    public record DateRange(LocalDate start,
                            LocalDate end) {
    }

    private final Pattern format = Pattern.compile(
        "(\\p{L}+)"                         // start month
        + "\\s*(\\d+)(?i:st|nd|rd|th)?"     // start day
        + "(?:,?\\s*(\\d+))?"               // start year (optional)
        + "\\s*\\p{Pd}"                     // dash separating start and end
        + "\\s*(\\p{L}+)?"                  // end month (optional)
        + "\\s*(\\d+)(?i:st|nd|rd|th)?"     // end day
        + "(?:,?\\s*(\\d+))?");             // end year (optional)

    private final NumberFormat numberFormat =
        NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();

    private final DateTimeFormatter monthFormat =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    public DateRange parse(String s)
    throws ParseException {
        Matcher matcher = format.matcher(s);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new ParseException(s, 0);
        }

        String startMonthStr = matcher.group(1);
        String startDayStr = matcher.group(2);
        String startYearStr = matcher.group(3);
        String endMonthStr = matcher.group(4);
        String endDayStr = matcher.group(5);
        String endYearStr = matcher.group(6);

        try {
            Month startMonth = Month.from(monthFormat.parse(startMonthStr));
            int startDay = numberFormat.parse(startDayStr).intValue();

            Integer startYear;
            if (startYearStr != null) {
                startYear = numberFormat.parse(startYearStr).intValue();
            } else {
                startYear = null;
            }

            Month endMonth;
            if (endMonthStr != null) {
                endMonth = Month.from(monthFormat.parse(endMonthStr));
            } else {
                endMonth = startMonth;
            }

            int endDay = numberFormat.parse(endDayStr).intValue();

            Integer endYear;
            if (endYearStr != null) {
                endYear = numberFormat.parse(endYearStr).intValue();
            } else {
                endYear = null;
            }

            if (startYear == null) {
                if (endYear == null) {
                    endYear = Year.now().getValue();
                }
                startYear = endYear;
            } else if (endYear == null) {
                endYear = startYear;
            }

            LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
            LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(endYear, endMonth, endDay);

            return new DateRange(start, end);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            ParseException pe = new ParseException(s, e.getErrorIndex());
            pe.initCause(e);
            throw pe;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws ParseException {
        String[] testInputs = {
            "January 16th – 21st, 2025",
            "January 16th – February 21st, 2025",
            "January 16th – February 21st, 2025",
            "December 16th 2024 – January 2nd 2025",
            "November 16th – 19th",
        };

        DateRangeParser parser = new DateRangeParser();
        for (String input : testInputs) {
            DateRange range = parser.parse(input);
            System.out.println(range);
        }
    }
}

Some notes about the regular expression:

\p{L}+ matches 1 or more letters.
\d+ maches 1 or more digits.
\p{Pd} matches any dash.  In your examples, you are using an en dash character ('\u2013'), not an ASCII hyphen.  This will match both.

\p{L} and \p{Pd} refer to Unicode general categories.
More information is available in the documentation for Pattern.
Using Month startMonth = Month.from(monthFormat.parse(string)) instead of just Month.valueOf(s.toUpperCase()) allows for localized matching of month names.  As Turo points out, if the computer is not set (or might not be set) to an English locale, but you want to parse English month names, you will have to specify English in the month format:
private final DateTimeFormatter monthFormat =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);


this code is not working

have you tried to run it ?

Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: January 16th – 21st, 2025

it fails on the first input

@khalifaR. I literally copied and pasted your input strings.  Perhaps you need to strip the input string before parsing it?

.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH) is critical for the monthFormat, when English is not the default

@VGR I think you got something wrong, I presume with the ',' Separator, the year is Start and End-Year

@khalifaR. Which line is throwing the ParseException?  Does the exception’s stack trace have a Caused by section?

I got the Exception,too, and adding withLocale made it disapear, as I mentioned in my comment

Yes, the Locale needs to be specified as the date strings are locale-specific and cannot be left to a default

Answer has been updated with setting of Locale.

The whole answer and code are well thought out (+1). With setting the locale as shown at the bottom of the answer the code works flawlessly for me.

the code is running but the output is wrong January 16th – 21st, 2025 should be DateRange[start=2025-01-16, end=2025-01-21] it is giving 2024 in the first date, since the year is mentioned in the second part that means the first date is also 2025?

@khalifaR. Fixed.

@khalifaR. so you will never have an overlapping range without a starting year.  Eg. August 16th – February 21st, 2025.  In this case, 2025 would not make sense.

solution is working now, but please add withLocal since solution is not working without it

java.time and ThreeTen Extra
Like the others I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. In this case you may supplement with the LocalDateRange class from ThreeTen Extra, a library developed alongside java.time and building on it (links at the bottom).
This answer features:

For ranges without years making sure they are interpreted in the present or future: the dates are taken to be in the remaining part of this year or in the next calendar year.
Precise parsing of ordinal dates (1st, 2nd, 16th, etc.) for good validation.
Use of LocalDateRange from ThreeTen Extra for a date range.
No need for regex (except for – for String.split() for initial splitting of the string) nor for explicit number parsing. All parsing work is carried out through DateTimeFormatter objects.
Pattern matching (since Java 14) for elegant cast of the parsed TemporalAccessor to LocalDate.

// For parsing 1st, 2nd, 16th, 21st, etc.
private static final Map<Long, String> ORDINAL_DAYS = createOrdinalDays();

private static Map<Long, String> createOrdinalDays() {
    Map<Long, String> dayMap = new HashMap<>();
    putSuffix(dayMap, "st", 1, 21, 31);
    putSuffix(dayMap, "nd", 2, 22);
    putSuffix(dayMap, "rd", 3, 23);
    for (long dayNumber = 1; dayNumber <= 31; dayNumber++) {
        dayMap.computeIfAbsent(dayNumber, d -> String.valueOf(d) + "th");
    }
    return dayMap;
}

private static void putSuffix(
        Map<Long, String> dayMap, String suffix, long... dayNumbers) {
    for (long dayNumber : dayNumbers) {
        dayMap.put(dayNumber, String.valueOf(dayNumber) + suffix);
    }
}

private static final DateTimeFormatter START_DATE_PARSER
        = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("MMMM ")
                .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, ORDINAL_DAYS)
                .appendPattern("[[,] u]")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

private static final DateTimeFormatter BASE_END_DATE_PARSER
        = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("[MMMM ]")
                .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, ORDINAL_DAYS)
                .appendPattern("[[,] u]")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

public static LocalDateRange parse(String input) {
    // Break into start and end strings
    String[] strings = input.split(" – ");
    if (strings.length != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input, must be two dates separated by a dash: " + input);
    }

    TemporalAccessor parsedStart = START_DATE_PARSER.parseBest(
            strings[0], LocalDate::from, MonthDay::from);

    // For end date use start month as default
    DateTimeFormatter endDateParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(BASE_END_DATE_PARSER)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR,
                    parsedStart.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR))
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    TemporalAccessor parsedEnd = endDateParser.parseBest(
            strings[1], LocalDate::from, MonthDay::from);

    LocalDate start;
    LocalDate endInclusive;
    // Have we got a year at all? If so, we should at least have end year
    if (parsedEnd instanceof LocalDate endLocalDate) { // Yes, we have end year
        endInclusive = endLocalDate;
        if (parsedStart instanceof LocalDate startLocalDate) {
            start = startLocalDate;
        } else {
            start = ((MonthDay) parsedStart).atYear(endLocalDate.getYear());
        }
    } else { // No, no years.
        if (parsedStart instanceof LocalDate) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input; start year requires end year: " + input);
        }

        // We need to calculate a year.
        // Find the next instance of the parsed start month and day.
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        MonthDay startMonthDay = (MonthDay) parsedStart;
        int year = today.getYear();
        if (startMonthDay.isBefore(MonthDay.from(today))) { // Over for this year; use next year
            year++;
        }
        start = startMonthDay.atYear(year);
        endInclusive = ((MonthDay) parsedEnd).atYear(year);
    }

    return LocalDateRange.ofClosed(start, endInclusive);
}

Let‘s try it out with your example strings:
    String[] testInputs = {
            "January 16th – 21st, 2025",
            "January 16th – February 21st, 2025",
            "December 16th 2024 – January 2nd 2025",
            "November 16th – 19th"
    };

    for (String testInput : testInputs) {
        LocalDateRange dateRange = parse(testInput);
        System.out.format(Locale.ROOT, "%37s -> %s - %s%n",
                testInput, dateRange.getStart(), dateRange.getEndInclusive());
    }

When run today output was:
            January 16th – 21st, 2025 -> 2025-01-16 - 2025-01-21
   January 16th – February 21st, 2025 -> 2025-01-16 - 2025-02-21
December 16th 2024 – January 2nd 2025 -> 2024-12-16 - 2025-01-02
                 November 16th – 19th -> 2024-11-16 - 2024-11-19

I am using DateTimeFormatter.parseBest() for parsing a string that may or may not contain a year, into a LocalDate if the year is present and into a MonthDay if it isn‘t. The latter class is used for a month and day of month without a year. When later I determine a year, I convert into a LocalDate.
LocalDateRange forces us to choose whether our date ranges are half-open (from start inclusive to end exclusive) or closed (including both start and end). I took your ranges to be closed since user-readable date intervals often are while computers work better and more naturally with half-open intervals.
I can‘t tell whether my code exactly fulfils your requirements in corner cases; but you can always modify it to your exact needs.
Avoid java.util.Date
You wrote:

I want to convert the strings in the following format
to java.util.Date range, …

The java.uil.Date class had bad design problems, which was why it along with several other date and time classes from java.util and java.text was supplanted by java.time in Java 8 more than 10 years ago. There is no reason why you should want to use anything else than java.time.
Tip: ISO 8601 Time Intervals
If you can, rather than exchanging and parsing your human-readable date ranges, use the better machine-readable ISO 8601 time intervals like 2025-01-16/2025-01-21 for data exchange. They are still human-readable, but a lot easier to parse. Use good human-readable formats only for presentation to your user.
The LocalDateRange class I have used has a parse method that directly parses an ISO 8601 interval of dates like 2025-01-16/2025-01-21, which solves your entire problem without any coding.
Links

Oracle Tutorial Trail: Date Time
ThreeTen Extra Home
ISO 8601 Time Intervals on Wikipedia


Great answer! Thank you!

Assumptions based on questions and comments.

All possible range formats have been presented.
Each range format has a unique number of fields to process.
All fields start with the starting month and day so those fields can be extracted outside of the switch block.

The Process

First, parse each range field using the regex and store in a LinkedList keeping track of the fields processed.
Then for each of type of Date, create StringBuilders for starting and ending Dates and grab the appropriate token and append it to the StringBuilder
Then each created starting and ending date can be formatted as required.

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ParsingRanges {

    public record Range(LocalDate start, LocalDate end, DateTimeFormatter dtf) {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "%s - %s".formatted(start.format(dtf), end.format(dtf) );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String regex = "(?:(\\w+)[\\s\\-–,]*)";

        List<Range> processed = new ArrayList<>();
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d[,] yyyy");

        String[] ranges = {"January 16th – 21st, 2025", // 4 fields
                "January 1st – February 21st, 2025", // 5 fields
                "January 16th  – August 21st, 2025",
                "December 16th 2024 – January 2nd 2025", // 6 fields
                "November 16th – 19th"}; // 3 fields
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        for (String t : ranges) {
            LinkedList<String> tokens = new LinkedList<>();
            int fields = 0;
            // remove day ordinal designations and trailing comma
            t = t.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(th|nd|st|rd|,)", "");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
            while (m.find()) {
                tokens.add(m.group(1));
                fields++;
            }

            StringBuilder start = new StringBuilder(tokens.get(0)).append(" ")
                    .append(tokens.get(1)).append(" ");
            StringBuilder end = new StringBuilder();
            switch (fields) {
                case 3: { // three fields
                    start.append(Year.now());
                    end.append(tokens.get(0)).append(" ").append(tokens.get(2))
                            .append(" ").append(Year.now());
                    break;
                }
                case 4: { // four fields
                    start.append(tokens.getLast()); // year
                    end.append(tokens.getFirst()).append(" ")
                            .append(tokens.get(2)).append(" ")
                            .append(tokens.get(3));
                    break;
                }
                case 5: { // five fields
                    start.append(tokens.getLast()); // year
                    end.append(tokens.get(2)).append(" ").append(tokens.get(3))
                            .append(" ").append(tokens.get(4));
                    break;
                }
                case 6: { // six fields
                    
                    start.append(tokens.get(2)); // year
                    end.append(tokens.get(3)).append(" ").append(tokens.get(4))
                            .append(" ").append(tokens.get(5));
                    break;
                }
            };

            LocalDate s = LocalDate.parse(start, dtf);
            LocalDate e = LocalDate.parse(end, dtf);
            
            processed.add(new Range(s, e, dtf));
        }
        for (Range range : processed) {
            System.out.println(range);
        }
    }

}

prints
January 16, 2025 - January 21, 2025
January 16, 2025 - February 16, 2025
January 16, 2025 - August 21, 2025
December 16, 2024 - January 02, 2025
November 16, 2024 - November 19, 2024

Note that the DateTimeFormater and Locale may need to be changed to satisfy your ultimate requirements.
I opted to store the starting and ending dates as well as the LocalDate formatter in a record.

It‘s very fine to list your assumptions first thing in the text. I recommend that the reader also considers checks those assumptions in their code.

@Anonymous  Thanks for the comments.  I had already done a check on the months  for an ordinal conflict and knew about st in August.  Then I quickly forgot to fix it.  I changed the regex to ensure that the ordinal is preceded by a digit.  Regarding your other comment, I wasn't clear on the recommendation.  Was that directed to others or me?  Again, thanks!

Primarily to the OP and others. Assumptions are dangerous, so in my view you would improve the answer if you either remind everyone to check the assumptions or you check the assumptions in code yourself. I remain unsure to what extend the input variations may be orthogonal so that a 4 field input might also be November 16th – December 3rd.

@Anonymous  As the variation of the fields and range formats evolve, this gets more and more complex.  Almost to the point of needing a FSM with additional checking or using something like ANTLR. That is why I stated what the OP said in that those were the only format variations.   One such variation I considered was when there were implied year overlaps.  E.g. (August 23rd - March 4th 2025).  In that case, the starting year must be specified to be the prior year of 2024.  Otherwise it can't be processed.   So my field count of 5 would need to handle two variations.

You can use the following code:
public class Test {

   public Test() {
      String[] allDates = {
         "January 16th – 21st, 2025",
         "January 16th – February 21st, 2025",
         "January 16th – February 21st, 2025",
         "December 16th 2024 – January 2nd 2025",
         "November 16th – 19th" };
      for( int i = 0; i < allDates.length; i ++ ) {
         String[] twoDates = allDates[ i ].split( " – " );  //  "January 16th", "21st, 2025"
         LocalDate[] dates = translate( twoDates );
      }
   }

   LocalDate[] translate( String[] twoDates ) {
      LocalDate out[] = new LocalDate[ 2 ];
      String inheritedMonth = twoDates[ 0 ].split( " " )[ 0 ];  //  January
      out[ 0 ] = getDate( twoDates[ 0 ].replace( ",", "" ).split( " " ), inheritedMonth );
      out[ 1 ] = getDate( twoDates[ 1 ].replace( ",", "" ).split( " " ), inheritedMonth );
      return out;
   }

   public LocalDate getDate( String[] date, String inheritedMonth ) {
      int day = -1, year = -1, month = -1;           
      switch( date.length ) {
         case 3:
            year = Integer.parseInt( date[ 2 ] );
            month = getMonth( date[ 0 ] );
            day = getDay( date[ 1 ] );
            break;
         case 2:
            if( date[ 0 ].substring( 0, 1 ).matches( "[a-zA-Z]" ) ) {
               year = LocalDate.now().getYear();
               month = getMonth( date[ 0 ] );
               day = getDay( date[ 1 ] );
            }
            else {
               year = Integer.parseInt( date[ 1 ] );
               month = getMonth( inheritedMonth );
               day = getDay( date[ 0 ] );
            }  break;
         case 1:
            year = LocalDate.now().getYear();
            month = getMonth( inheritedMonth );
            day = getDay( date[ 0 ] );
            break;
         default:
            break;
      }
      return LocalDate.of( year, month, day );
   }

   int getMonth( String month ) {
      return Month.valueOf( month.toUpperCase() ).getValue();
   }

   int getDay( String day ) {
      return Integer.parseInt( day.replaceAll( "[a-zA-Z]", "" ) );
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Test test = new Test();
   }
}

Note: When I tested the code, the same failure, I checked everything and there were no errors, after a long “struggle”, I discovered that the line String[] twoDates = allDates[ i ].split( “ - ” ); did not perform the split, it did not seem to make any sense, poor and poor until I found the problem.
I can't describe it accurately, just point out where it is and how to fix it.
Somehow I don't understand, the “ - ‘ that I passed as a parameter, is not the same as the one you passed as an example (ex: ’January 16th - 21st, 2025” ), the solution was to copy from your example the pattern and paste it in the call to split.
